# Create a user account under the root in linux

Tags: linux

I want to create a user in Linux and  add two user. But i want that Both user cannot access tha data with each other. In case if OS corrupt then tha data will stored in another location for future use. Because if the os corrupt then  the os will corrupt not the data because the data stored in another location. How is it possible

Comment: Adn you basically cannot do what you want. Malicious people with `root` priviledges could break your system.

Comment: @ aix  i want to create a two user in a machine. Each user have a permission but they cannot share the data and in case if the OS corrupt but the user cannot lost their data, it found in the another location like the backup drive

Comment: Do you mean "under the root directory" or users with root privileges?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how is anyone supposed to understand anything from this ? What is a user having permission ? On what ? The root home (/root) ? The system's root (/) ? What does "cannot share data" mean ? If the users have permissions on either /root or /, they can share data anyway. Maybe you could try to draw a sketch, or correct your grammar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to give someone root privileges but not give them full access to the system  you may want to look at SUDO. The config file is located in /etc/sudoers

Here is a website explaining how to configure sudo:  [LINK](http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/sudo/) (linuxhelp.net)

This will allow you to define exactly what access and privileges the user can have. Also you should look at user, group, and world permissions with chmod.

Adding users to a group is in /etc/groups

Best of luck!